# New Windows user need help installIng Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Hey guys I am long time Windows user I love Ubuntu but I need help with installing Ubumtu on my ASUS Laptop I need someone walk me through it pherphas via Skype  I would really appreciate it

Specs I5 Processer 
256 GB SSD 
8 RAM
Bluetooth 4.1 
Wireless built in of course

Comment: At youtube there are so many tutorials regarding Ubuntu installation, it explains step by step. Its not the hardest thing nowadays. The things are becoming exciting after installation. Here is a nice doc what really helped me: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/Home A week ago I just switched to Ubuntu from Win so I understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest ISO from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso?_ga=1.102219137.1273412395.1476707984).
2. Download and run [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.8.exe) program.
3. Select the appropriate options, and burn the ISO to a USB stick
4. Open Disk Management, and shrink your main partition by how much you want to leave for Ubuntu. **Leave it as unallocated.**
5. Reboot, and boot from the USB stick instead of the hard disk.
6. Wait for it to boot, and follow the prompts to install. If you select "install alongside Windows", it should automatically install the the unallocated space you created earlier.

Comment: __Do not use UUI.__ Use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie).

Comment: @Zacharee1 Why? Everybody always has problems with Rufus, but UUI almost always works.

Comment: I've always seen the exact opposite of that. Every time someone has a problem with UUI/Unetbootin/LILO/etc, Rufus always fixes it.